# why could not add folder to current git repo

Tags: git

Now I copied a folder into current repo, but I could not add the new folder into the repo. Then I tried using this command(`git version 2.26.3`):

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/retire% git add zuul-service 
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/retire% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

seems did not add success, I tried using this command to force add to the repo:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/retire% git add --force zuul-service 
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/retire% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

still not work. the next I tried to modify the folder `zuul-service` file, no file change tips when using `git status` to check. I also check the root folder's `.gitignore` and did not find ignore the `zuul-service` folder. This is my first time to encount this strange problem and I have no clue about this problem. Where is going wrong and what should I do to add the `zuul-service` folder into current repo? This is the project structure:

[image]

this is my `.gitignore` files content:

```
# Compiled class file
*.class

# Log file
*.log
log

# BlueJ files
*.ctxt

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar
*.icloud
*.bin
*.lock

.idea

*.tmp

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*

# dolphin-music
dolphin-music/dolphin-music-api/build/
dolphin-music/dolphin-music-service/build/
dolphin-music/dolphin-music-service/testngOutput
dolphin-music/dolphin-music-service/out

# dolphin-post
dolphin-post/dolphin-post-api/build/
dolphin-post/dolphin-post-service/build/
dolphin-post/dolphin-post-service/testngOutput
dolphin-post/dolphin-post-service/out

dolphin-acientbay/dolphin-acientbay-api/build
dolphin-acientbay/dolphin-acientbay-service/build
dolphin-acientbay/dolphin-acientbay-service/testngOutput
dolphin-acientbay/dolphin-acientbay-service/out

dolphin-common/build/
dolphin-common-biz/build/

dolphin-manage/dolphin-manage-service/out

eureka-service/out/

.gradle

.DS_Store

.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/buildOutputCleanup.lock
.idea/workspace.xml

dolphin-manage/dolphin-manage-service/out

dolphin-template/dolphin-template-service/out

dolphin-acientbay/dolphin-acientbay-service/out
```

the first time, the folder `zuul-service` contains a `.git` dir. then I removed it using this command:`git rm -rf .git`. now the dir did not contains `.git` folder.

Comment: the folder `zuul-servcie` contains files. @MarekR

Comment: Might not be relevant, but I'm curious: what does the blue square thingy overlaying the bottom corner of a folder-icon imply?

Comment: if the files part of repo, why I changed files on the `zuul-service` sub folders could not give me a tips when using `git status`? @vakio

Comment: Does `zuul-service` contain a `.git` directory (hidden)?

Comment: first it have `.git`, then I removed it. @dan1st

Comment: Does that change anything? Does it work now?

Comment: I think it should work, but it does not. I did not know which step I made a mistake. @dan1st

Comment: Can you create a file called `test.txt` there? Does this change the result of `git status`? Does `zuul-service` contain a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: when I changed the file under zuul-service folder, it would not change when using `git status`, the .gitignore in the zuul-service was deleted. @dan1st

Comment: What happens when typing `git status` in `zuul-service`?

Comment: Is `zuul-service` a symlink?

Comment: No, it is not a symlink. @KamilCuk

Comment: when I change the file and using `git status` git check, shows:`On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean`@dan1st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the first time [I ran `git add zuul-service`], the folder `zuul-service` contain[ed] a `.git` dir.

That would do it.  Git would add `zuul-service` as a *gitlink*, the operational half of a submodule.  From this point on, the Git in which `zuul-service` was added is a *superproject* and `zuul-service` is a *submodule* within it.

> then I removed it using this command: `git rm -rf .git`.

That would not work:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git rm -rf .git
fatal: pathspec '.git' did not match any files
```

What *would* work is `rm -rf .git`, or `rm -rf zuul-folder/.git` if you are still in the superproject repository.  I'll assume that this is what you did.

> now the dir [does not contain a] `.git` folder.

That's good and necessary (assuming that this *result* is what you want), but there is one more step to take: in the superproject, we need to stop it from being a superproject holding a gitlink for `zuul-service`, using:

```
git rm -f zuul-service
```

If you had added it as a proper submodule (with `git submodule add`) rather than just as a gitlink, there would be more to do here; see [How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1260748/1256452)

Once there's no longer a gitlink in the way, `git add zuul-service` should work as you expected it to work earlier.